# How to change resharpers default access modifier to public instead of internal for generated classes?

Tags: c#, resharper

when you auto generate a class, by default resharper seems to go with `internal class Blah`,  but I'd like it to default to `public class Blah`

I can understand why, because at that moment of generation, it is only internally scoped, but very quickly I will use it publicly scoped. Which requires an auto fixup, which is just annoying.   I'd like to be able specify the default access modifier

I have 2017.1.2

The way I generate the class is as following :-

`var x = new Blah()` <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> -> Create Type /Generate Class

[image]

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure if I set this a long time ago and the settings get applied through either my visual studio login or my jetbrains login - but when I generate a C# class in ReSharper from the solution explorer it does default to public.  So guess I'm trying to say it is definitely doable

Comment: @RobertPetz that's what I'm thinking, it's ironic as there is another question on SO that asks the opposite, R# used to generate public and theywanted internal, but now does internal by default.  The answer to that was it wasn't configurable, but I'm picking it is now.

Comment: how are you auto-generating a class? by templates (i.e. typing "class")? if so, you can just edit the `class` template in the Templates Explorer.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'm running 2017.1.3 (so the latest) so maybe it changed between that old question and now.  If you are using Templates though I can concur with Ilian

Comment: by using it, then generating it,  so   ```var x = new Blah() <ALT-ENTER -> Generate Class>```

Comment: @KeithNicholas WOW interesting - that is defaulting to internal for me as well.  So the templates are defaulted to private (by not writing private), generate from a missing reference defaults to internal, and generate from 'alt-insert' on the solution tree defaults to public

Answer (score -1):

You have to modify the templates.
Resharper => Tools => Template Explorer choose Live/File Templates for the c#.
Now you can edit to whatever you like.

[Templates Explorer Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Templates_Explorer.html)

***edit***:

Seems that you are invoking through "quick fixes" suggestions. Probably related to the "search/replace patterns". Didnt see the default exposed though.

Comment: as mentioned in the comments, this is not what I'm triggering.